# Angular Forms. How to Get Some Inputs to Reevaluate Others?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

I have a form in angular that that a Category text input and an ID input. The ID must be unique to the category. So if I have the following items for `Cat1`:

```
Cat1 - 123
Cat1 - 245
Cat1 - 456
```

Then If i tried to enter a new item with the category `Cat1` and the id `123` then that input wouldn't be unique to the category and the form could not be submitted. If the id changed to `1234` then it would be valid.

To achieve this I have a custom directive called `unique` that required `ngModel`. It looks like this-

HTML-

```
<input name="ID"
       required
       unique="id in getItemsByCategory(newCategory)"
       type="text"
       ng-model="newId"></input>
```

JS-

```
.directive('unique', function() {
    return {
      require: '^ngModel',
      link: function(scope, ele, attr, ngModelController) {
        ngModelController.$validators.unique = function(val) {
          var uniqueInRegex = /([^\s]+)\s+in\s([^\s]+)/i;

          var matches = attr.unique.match(uniqueInRegex);
          var property = matches[1];
          var collection = scope.$eval(matches[2]);

          for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            var item = collection[i];
            if(item[property] === val) {
              console.log('not unique');
              return false;
            }
          }

          console.log('unique');
          return true;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Which works fine:

[image]

But if the validator finds the field is not unique based on the category, and the category field changes, then the validator doesn't reevaulate.

[image]

Here is a JSBin of what what's seen in these gifs:

http://jsbin.com/wubesutugo/edit?html,js,output

Is there anyway I can have one input "touch" another input when it changes? I want this validation directive to be generic because i have multiple places I'd like to use it. So I don't want this logic in the controller.

Comment: I have found a solution but I'll leave this question open a little longer if there is a better solution. On the Category input I have an ng-change that looks like this- `<input name="Cat" ng-change="NewItemForm.ID.$validate()" required type="text" ng-model="newCategory"></input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution with the `ng-change` is sufficient. An alternative would be using a watch (`$watchCollection`, to be precise):

```
.directive('unique', function() {
    var uniqueInRegex = /([^\s]+)\s+in\s([^\s]+)/i;
    return {
      require: '^ngModel',
      link: function(scope, ele, attr, ngModelController) {
        var matches = attr.unique.match(uniqueInRegex);
        var property = matches[1];
        var collectionExpr = matches[2];

        scope.$watchCollection(collectionExpr, function(newval) {
          ngModelController.$validate();
        });

        ngModelController.$validators.unique = function(val) {
          var collection = scope.$eval(collectionExpr);
          for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            var item = collection[i];
            if(item[property] === val) {
              console.log('not unique');
              return false;
            }
          }

          console.log('unique');
          return true;
        };
      }
    };
})
```

(Also demonstrates calculating the regular expression just once.)

Try it: http://jsbin.com/wiyugozuje/1/edit?js,console,output